# 11-46 cassette with 48 chainring for commute bike

Tags: gears, drivetrain

I'm building a new commute bike.  Would like to consider the idea of using single chainring with 11-46 cassette.  Looking at the ratio, 48 front with 46 rear should give me the climbing option I need.  What is the disadvantage of this setup vs 2x11 or 2x10?

I'm getting similar overall range. There are big jumps, but that doesn't bother me as much.  I'm thinking the catch would the shifting experience. (i.e., shifting with 11-46 cassette might not be as smooth as 105's 11-34)   Is that it?

Comment: A 1x11 or 2x11 speed drivetrain is pretty fancy for a commuter (especially one used for wet weather or something) -- 8 or 9 speed drivetrains are significantly cheaper and the closer ratios likely won't come into play in commuting unless your commute is racing.

Answer (score 2):

The advantages of 1x11

- 11 fairly evenly spaced gears
- Can use narrow-wide chain for decreasing chain jump.
- "lighter" by some small amount
- mechanically simpler

The disadvantages

- Gaps between gears are larger than on a 2x10 or 11
- you need a really big back cog for low gears rather than having a smaller secondary front chainring.  This adds weight and its at the back.
- You need a fancy rear derailleur capable of handing all this spare chain.
- This all increases cost.

I believe theres a 10-50 cassette in the sram line now - marketted as "Eagle"

Comment: Shimano MTB rear derailleurs can handle 11-46. There's nothing fancy in 50$ RD-M7000.

Comment: Eagle is 12 speed and it pretty much has to be used as a system.